# GAE store to db but not display on view

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I have google app engine aplication. I use JPA and simple servlet and jsp.

My code:

```
Training training = new Training();
    training.setCoachName(req.getParameter("coachName"));
    training.setDate(req.getParameter("date"));
    training.setTime(req.getParameter("time"));
    EntityManager entityManager = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(training);
        entityManager.flush();           
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    resp.sendRedirect("/overview");
```

and servlet for view list of trainings

```
EntityManager entityManager = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select t from " + Training.class.getName() + " t ");
    List<Training> result = q.getResultList();
    req.setAttribute("trainigs", result);
    entityManager.close();
    RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
```

Problem is, that I store to db record, but on index.jsp is not displayed. After I try sometimes refresh page, then record is there. So between storing record and displaying on jsp is delay some seconds.

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you encountered is a Datastore property called [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

What basically happens is this: when you write data to HRD it writes data to tables and then returns, before indexes were built (= indexes are built asynchronously). Since queries need indexes, they do not find the newly written data until indexes are built.

Solutions (read more about it at above link):

1. Use get instead of query. Gets are always strongly consistent. Restructure your app, so that you pass the key of the newly saved data to the view JSP, do the query as usual and then add newly written data to the list via get.
2. Use Ancestor queries as described in the link (imho, a bad solution in your case).